# Mapping class hierarchy through fluent nhibernate by using 2 strategies

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, hierarchy, fluent, class-hierarchy

I want to combine table-per-class and table-per-hierarchy strategies using fluent nhibernate or nhibernate itself(I mean hbm files), but I don't know how. I prefer fluent over hbm but if it's impossible, then hbm is also fine. I tested this by introducing Entity as ClassMap and all other as SubClassMap in fluent but then in hbm files generated by fluent, Entity was a class and all other were joined-classes which is not what I want. I will describe the problem in more detail below.

Class hierarchy:

```
    public class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Person : Entity
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class SystemUser : Person
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have one table for entity and one for person and all kinds of it(all its subclasses).I mean I want to use table-per-class strategy for Entity and table-per-hierarchy strategy for Person and SystemUser classes. Database structure is something like this:

```
EntityTable(ID(PK),Name)
PersonTable(EntityID(PK,FK),Phone,Password)
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if EntityTable Id is not database generated (which is discouraged by NH anyways) you can use the trick

```
public PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Table("PersonTable");

        Id(p => p.Id, "EntityID").GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("PersonType");

        Map(x => x.Phone);

        Join("EntityTable", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("ID");
            join.Map(p => p.Name);
        });
    }
}


public SystemUserMap : SubclassMap<SystemUser>
{
    public SystemUserMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but no,This is not what I want. Pleas look at the database structure and the two tables. one for Entity and one for all kinds of person.infact person is abstract.

Comment: the mapping is for the posted table structure. you have a hirarchy for the Person and a hierarchy for SystemUser, but both share EntityTable for theire name property. Try using `SchemaExport(config).Execute(true, false, false)` in a console app to see what i mean

Comment: other than what i posted i cant think of a way because NH doesnt allow discriminatetocolumn in a `<join>`

Comment: based on what you've suggested I have 3 tables: Table("SystemUserTable") and  Table("PersonTable") and Join("EntityTable"... but I have only 2 tables Entity and Person and SystemUser goes to person table.do you get my point?

Comment: Ok, better but again remove Table("SystemUserTable"); from SystemUserMap! and the point here is that the ID is generated in Entity and as you can see I have no ID property on my Person class - which you've mentioned. If I declare it as ClassMap it requires ID which belongs to Entity Table and if I declare it SubClassMap then I can't use DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn. this is the problem now.

Comment: to don't have a map for Entity at all is the trick here to use `discriminateSubclassesOn` which is only feasible if Id is generated in Code and not DB. Other than that you have to write your own `EntityPersistor` which is tricky and a lot of work.